# ggplot continuous x-axis labelled with data from variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis

I am plotting data over time using the following dataset:

```
dt1 <- data.table(
sender=c("boy", "girl", "girl", "boy", "girl", "boy"), 
type = c("run", "walk", "run", "run", "run", "walk"), 
time=c(as.POSIXct("2014-02-19 03:24:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-19 03:29:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-20 03:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-23 03:34:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-25 08:24:00"), as.POSIXct("2014-02-25 09:45:00")), 
dayRelative = c(0,0,1,4,6,6))
```

The following ggplot command works fine:

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x=time, y=sender, colour=type)) +  
geom_point(size=2, position=position_jitter(width=0.2, height=0.2)) + 
scale_y_discrete(limit = c("boy", "girl"), labels= c("Boy", "Girl"))
```

[image: Resulting Chart]

What I like to achieve is that instead of having the date labels on the x-axis, the data from the `dayRelative`-column should be used. That means for the dots the `time`-column should be used, however, the x-Axis should use the data from the `dayRelative` column the respective places. As a result Feb 19 should be replaced by 0, Feb 20 by 1, ...

Comment: You can just replace `time` with `dayRelative` in the call to `ggplot`? What wil be the difference?

Comment: @BBrill The the dots are positioned by the less accurate variable `dayRelative`. `time` includes the exact time, `dayRelative` only the days passed since the beginning. I would like to have these days as labels on the x-Axis, still the dots should represent the exact times (like 9:00 on the first day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale_x_datetime()` and provide `time` as `breaks=` and `dayRelative` as `labels=`. Around the dt1$time used function `trunc()` to get only day without hours and minutes and then `as.POSIXct` to have POSIXct object to use it in `scale_x_datetime()`.

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x=time, y=sender, colour=type)) +  
      geom_point(size=2, position=position_jitter(width=0.2, height=0.2)) + 
      scale_y_discrete(limit = c("boy", "girl"), labels= c("Boy", "Girl"))+
      scale_x_datetime(breaks=as.POSIXct(trunc(dt1$time,"day")),labels=dt1$dayRelative)
```

[image]

Comment: This works in principle, but does not format nicely when there are many data points: for example it puts the label "6" as many times on the axis as it occurs. Is it possible to adjust this to include each label only once as Day 1, 2, 3, 4,... but not 0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2 (which is produced with my larger dataset)?

Comment: In your question you wrote that "x-axis should show 0,0,1,4,6,6...", so I answered as you asked. Will try to change the answer.

Comment: You are right, sorry for the confusion. I tried to adjust my question to reflect this.

Comment: Updated my answer with another solution